# How to Change Class Name Based on Array's Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm a JavaScript newbie so kindly use accessible language.

From the code below, I want to change the class name on certain array elements;
that is for elements `orange, yellow, violet` to use class `btn btn-outline-dark` instead. Also, can this be done without adding id or class attributes that's not Bootstrap inside the html (something like `document.getElementById()` is not desirable)?

I tried:

```
function Rainbow(){
    body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index % colors.length]
    index++
    if(index=1,index=2,index=5){
        button.className = 'btn btn-outline-dark'
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Full code (also feel free to improve/fix anything else inside):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Rainbow Colors</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row vh-100 d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light">Rainbow</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <script>
            const colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','violet'],
            body = document.querySelector('body'),
            button = document.querySelector('button')
            let index = 1

            body.style.backgroundColor = colors[0]
            button.onclick = Rainbow

            function Rainbow(){
                body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index % colors.length]
                index++
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you might be looking for, I'm not sure which version of JS you are using but here's an answer

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Rainbow Colors</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row vh-100 d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light">Rainbow</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <script>
            const colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','violet'],
            body = document.querySelector('body'),
            button = document.querySelector('button')
            let index = 1

            body.style.backgroundColor = colors[0]
            button.onclick = Rainbow

            function Rainbow(){
                body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index % colors.length]
                color = index % colors.length;
                index++; 
                if(color == 1 || color == 2 || color == 5){
                    button.className = 'btn btn-outline-dark'
                }
                else{
                    button.className = 'btn btn-outline-light'
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works but writing `btn btn-outline-light` twice, one in the html page and another one in JavaScript feels redundant. Any better way of doing it?

Comment: @user3134685 it is because to revert the state of button in another condition or else it'd be outline dark after one condition, And mark my answer as correct if it has helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this line:

```
if(index=1,index=2,index=5){
```

doesn't do what you think it does. `=` is the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) and `,` creates [compound expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), neither of which will help with what you likely intend.

Try this instead:

```
if(index == 1 || index == 2 || index == 5){
```

`||` is the [logical `or` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and `==` is the [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Doesn't work without hesitantly adding `else{button.className = 'btn btn-outline-light}` as it feels redundant. Any way of doing it without writing `btn btn-outline-light` twice, one in the html page and another one in JavaScript.

Comment: @user3134685 That's not redundant man, It is used like that to revert the state of button, I hope you get my point

Comment: @user3134685 You'll have to do something like that regardless. An alternative (but essentially the same thing) is to have the main button style be what `btn-outline-light` does and then have an additional class that you add/remove in javascript that overrides the necessary styles to give the button the alternate look.